# Put ListAdapter inside Dialog Android

Tags: android, dialog, listadapter

I currently display my search results by setListAdapter.  I want to display this in a dialog and cannot figure out how.  Here is the code I use to create my adapter:

> setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.location_entry, WeatherData.getSingleton(getActivity().getApplication()).getLocNames()));

Is there any way to insert this into a dialog and still have the results clickable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

isn't it like you can make a list in the dialog by some build in functions? You could just pass the object to the dielog and iterate through to create a list
Or you can always add a view, like an adapter view

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

or

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
builder.setView(layout);   // YOur view goes here
alertDialog = builder.create();
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use the [`setAdapter()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setAdapter%28android.widget.ListAdapter,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29) method on the builder:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(...), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {...} );
builder.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AlertDialog.Builder and set the list items via the [setSingleChoiceItems method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setSingleChoiceItems%28android.widget.ListAdapter,%20int,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29).